# What does "Backing forward or backing back" in Hillary Rodham Clinton’s comment mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I found the phrase *backing forward or backing back* in Secretary State Hillary Clinton’s remark on the Sunday Show, which was quoted in today’s Washington Post as follows.

> Secretary of State Hillary Rodham Clinton continued making the rounds on the Sunday shows to discuss the fast-evolving situation in Egypt. "This is a complex, very difficult situation," said Clinton, "We do not want to send any message about backing forward or backing back."

What does *backing forward or backing back* mean? Does it mean *keep positive support to Mubarak regime* or *Withdraw support to Mubarak regime*, or simply mean *move back and fro*, or *move back further* on U.S. policy toward Egypt?

Comment: That's a damn good question.

Comment: Robusto. Thank you. It's first time my question was commented a good question by English pundits since I started to post questions from last year-end.

Comment: … And always twirling, twirling toward freedom!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are right; it refers to American support either for Mubarak or his opposition. Her phrasing is a bit odd, but I'd interpret it like this:

- *backing* = supporting
- *back* = those who want to go back to the old situation, Mubarak in power
- *forward* = those who want to go forward to a new government

> "We do not want to send any message
>   [to either party] about [our]
>   *supporting those who want change or
>   those who want to go back to the way
>   things were*."

Comment: Cerberus. Your gloss (backing, back, forword) is easily understandable and helpful. Then, it grammatically make sense, because I felt uneasy with the expression of ‘backing back or backing forward’ as I took ‘back’ and ‘forward’ for an adverb.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: That is understandable. I must say that I found this way of saying it a bit unusual; but it is the only interpretation I could think of, and it must obviously mean something like for or against Mubarak.

Answer (score 7):

This is what happens when a politician can't think of anything truly useful to say but has to say something anyway. What Mrs. Clinton really means is something like

> I need to appear on press shows to talk about the situation, and I need to be seen to be out in front of this very dangerous predicament, but — wow, I sure wish I could talk about something else because the one thing I *can't* do is appear to be coming down on one side or the other because *whichever* side ultimately comes out on top will remember if I said something in support of the loser and then *we* will be the losers: we'll lose a very important ally in the Middle East ... which may be going to happen anyway because, well, *not* supporting the winning side can sometimes be as bad as supporting the losing side.
>
> So, given all of the above, I'm going to try to split hairs as finely as they have ever been split, and I give you now a new level of nonsense-speak which will undoubtedly be lampooned on *Fox News* and *The Daily Show* alike, but what the hell can I do about it? 'Backing-forward' and 'backing-back' are the best I could come up with. You think you could do better?

I sympathize, Mrs. Clinton, I really do. But nonsense is nonsense.

Comment: +1. Robusto for Secretary of State! At least when he has to say gobbledygook, you'll know what he means.

Comment: Alex. I learnt a new word, 'gobbledygook' by placing this question. Is it gobbledy ＋

Comment: Alex. I learnt a new word, 'gobbledygook' by placing this question, which I find a great benefit of this forum. It seems to me to mean nonsense. Is it a compound of 'gobbledy ＋gook'? How frequently being used?

Comment: Very nice. In her situation I'd say something like "Egypt is a sovereign country, and it is not our place to pick sides in a foreign political conflict or a civil war". It wouldn't be true, of course, since countries pick sides all the time; but it might sound convincing to more than 0 people. // So do you really think she meant "backing" as a movement, and "back" and "forward" as the directions of that movement? Then her expression is even uglier than I imagined it in my interpretation.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: 'Gobbledygook' is a word of American origin. It is meant to represent the 'gobble' sound a turkey makes.

Comment: @Cerberus: If she meant *forward* and *back* in the sense of progressive vs. regressive, then she definitely failed in her attempt to obfuscate her meaning, and instead by her words would be championing the uprising — something I am almost certain she would not have done (or been allowed to do). I think the statement is deliberately vague and ambiguous — in fact, raises the bar for vagueness by several notches — and is designed to make people scratch their heads and fail, ultimately, to parse anything from the sentence that might pin her down to a position.

Comment: @Robusto: I suppose I may have applied the principle of charity where it isn't wanted...

Comment: @YoichiOishi: to add to what @ElendilTheTall said, "gobbledygook" is an Americanism for text that's made deliberately hard to understand (like most of what politicians and bureaucrats say or write). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobbledygook for details.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a native speaker of the English language, I do hope Secretary Clinton's use of the word '*backing*' could also help clarify the difference, if any, between the common US usage of the word 'back' – such as 'I've got your back' (essentially meaning 'I support you') and the UK usage of the word '*backing* '– 'you have my backing' (also meaning 'you have my support'?). This is just an aside from what the secretary of state said in the quoted statement.

Comment: Possibly, a comment, not an answer?